# Coloring dots in scatterplot diagram by Axis Label value

Tags: excel, charts

I have a dataset from which I have plotted a scatter diagram as shown in the image. I would like to color the dots based on the first column values, because they recur in the dataset, so that I can identify points corresponding to various column values.

[image]

Comment: AFAIK the only solution for this involves some VBA

Comment: Ok, thanks. Any idea how I can use VBA to do that? Not much of a VBA maestro...

Comment: it would take someone generous enough to write the code for you - or you learning how to do it. If you want to learn I would suggest doing some research on line about changing the color points in a scatter plot chart, then building your code. If you get stuck, post another question here with the code you have and where you are stuck and people can help fix it. Also use the macro recorder. It can be useful in getting certain syntax to work with.

Comment: You can sort based on the first column, then create a separate data series for each journal name. Each data series can have its own color, marker shape, etc.